# Can I name an entity as "Property" in GreenDAO?

Tags: android, orm, greendao

Lets say you have a project and one of the tables or entities is named Property. This is giving me an error in my Android project. Why we ca't freely call our data model objects the names that we want regardless which ORM we use?

Answer (score 1):

After many hours I came to know that Property is a reserved word in greenDAO !!! so i changed it to Property_!

I know this sounds weird but if any one knows I am wrong please let me know.
No one ever posted anything related to this issue anywhere so I decided to save some ones time by posting it here.